# attaching locally stored mdf to SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Sorry if this question does not make sense, I have no experience with databases, I just stumbled upon this task.

I need to attach an mdf to a database. I have the mdf file stored in my local computer. When I click attach in SSMS, and then add, I can only browse the disks and folders of the SQL Server, while the file is in my local computer. How can I move the mdf file to the sql server?

Comment: Can you remote into the SQL Server computer?

Comment: ...or get to an exposed folder on it via UNC, or get to a network path that the server can also see. I'd also wonder why you have an MDF file as a backup and not a, well, backup,

Answer (score 1):

As Aaron Bertrand says in the comments, having a `.mdf` file as the method for adding a database to a server is unusual.  Normally you should have a `.bak` backup file.  If at all possible, contact your source and ask for backup to restore.

If you have to use an `.mdf` You need to copy it to the folder on the server, where it will become the `.mdf` of the database when it is live. Normally you would do this with an RDP or share connection to the folder. Be aware there are several issue you may encounter doing this.

See these related posts for the answer to questions you have not asked yet, but probably will.

- [Attaching MDF without LDF](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/12089/21924)
- [How to attach an .mdf file that was not properly detached?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/42762/21924)
- [Is is possible to recover a database from the 'raw' files (.mdf and .ldf) of the old server to a new SQL Server instance on a new server?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/111499/21924)